# Change image of imageview for 5 seconds and then restore original

Tags: android, imageview

I have set image's on 4 imageview's in XML file, now on button click I want to change images of all 4 imageview's. And after 5 seconds of button click, all the images should change to original images.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yes.. I have tried doing it by "Handler" .. didn't help. Then I tried doing it by calling 2 different methods in onClickListener with thread.sleep. This too didn't work.

Comment: Didn't help... how?

Comment: onClickListener itself gets executed after a delay of specified seconds. Means ...I first called a method neww() on button click, this will set new images to all imagiview's. After that oldd() method is called which restores the older images. I tried placing thread.sleep in neww() method.. in oldd() method.. as well as between calls made to these methods on button click. But the buttton click itself gets executed after the seconds specified. Same with "Handler".

Comment: That's wrong. Use @A.Wahab's answer. It will work. Read the comments and note where they suggest you change the images initially and where you change them in the end.

Comment: yesss.. done. :)

Comment: If it worked, you should accept their answer.

Comment: Done.. accepted..  actually I created my account today. So not much aware about things over here.

Comment: That's why there's a Help Center ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the thread like:

```
OnClick(View view){
  //change  the images of all images view  
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
        public void run() {
           //change  the images for all images view to previous ones 
          }
    }, 5000);

  }
```

Comment: `code`                                                                                                                        
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
{
   @Override
   public void run()
   {
       // Do something after 5s = 5000ms
       IV1.setImageResource(R.drawable.questionmark);
       IV2.setImageResource(R.drawable.questionmark);
       IV3.setImageResource(R.drawable.questionmark);
       IV4.setImageResource(R.drawable.questionmark)                                  
   }
 }, 5000);
 I have tried this.. doesn't work.